# IBM hyperlink in watson conversation

Tags: node.js, facebook, function, hyperlink, chatbot

I want to have a text in the hyperlink without showing the HTML tag. 
Other than editing Watson Conversation

"The link to go to Temasek Poly is: click https://www.google.com.sg\">Google.
"

Other than showing in the web application, can I show in facebook messenger?

I tried in facebook messenger but cannot, why? how can I do this same matter and can apply in facebook messenger

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not support your example, just paste the URL that you want to send for the user, like:

```
Search about this on https://google.com.br
```

And then, Facebook will transform in a hyperlink.

Done a lot of research on this...

> Facebook doesn't seem to support the usual codes which create
>   hyperlinked text (e.g. "Click here") that links the clicker to your
>   specified external website. for now, you can only attach a link in
>   it's full form (e.g. "www.blahblah.com")

Reference: Facebook forum [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=548602681841129).